# android HTML Scraping with Jsoup crashes

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask, web-scraping

I tried to write a Simple app that changes the TextView to the title on Google Html using Jsoup. But when I run it, the app crashes. Anyone have any idea why?
I think It might be something wrong with the Asynk task, can someone have a look at the code and tell me were the error is?

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class HttpExample extends Activity{

TextView tvResult;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.http);
    tvResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvHttp);

     new Title().execute();
}

 private class Title extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void>{
     String title;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com").get();
            // Get the html document title
            title = document.title();
        } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }//doInBackground()

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Set title into TextView
       tvResult.setText(title);

    }//onPostExecute()


    }//Title class


 }//Activity
```

Thank you so much for answering...

Comment: I tried it and doesn't crash. Did you add the permission to access Internet? What kind of Exception is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

In the android manifest file add the following permission and the application wont crash.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: you can't possibly _know_ that.

Comment: he didn't mentioned anything about adding the permission. so we can conclude that he didn't :)

Comment: the OP also did not mention the layout, so likewise we can conclude that the text view is not in the layout.

Comment: may be you are right or i am. let the OP add some more code part or clues to find out what exactly is the problem.